# Joining multiple child tables to one parent table WITHOUT getting all possible combinations

Tags: mysql, select

Assuming we have multiple child tables `child1, child2, child3...` with 1-to-n relationship to one parent table `parent`.

```
----------     ----------     ----------     ----------
| parent |     | child1 |     | child2 |     | child3 |
|--------|     |--------|     |--------|     |--------|
|parentID|     |child1ID|     |child2ID|     |child3ID|
----------     |parentID|     |parentID|     |parentID|
               ----------     ----------     ----------
```

What is the best way to get all related data to one record of parentID?

I tried `LEFT JOIN` but that resulted in a lot of unnecessary rows (all combinations, numRows parent x numRows child1 x numRows child2 x numRows child3). So I got very fast thousands of rows for just a bunch of real data rows:

```
SELECT
child1.child1ID,
child2.child2ID,
child3.child3ID
FROM parent
LEFT JOIN child1 ON child1.parentID = parent.parentID,
LEFT JOIN child2 ON child2.parentID = parent.parentID,
LEFT JOIN child3 ON child3.parentID = parent.parentID
WHERE parent.parentID = 1;
```

Is this the way it is intended? To my understanding the following happens here:

- child1 joins parent, a new derived table DT1 gets created
- child2 joins DT1 (and therefore parent and child1) and DT2 gets created
- child3 joins DT2 (and therefore parent, child1 and child2)

But that feels somehow wrong as the child tables should only be connected (joined) to parent. There is no relation in between the child tables.

The result is as follows (if all child tables have 2 rows):

```
child1ID | child2ID | child3ID
   1     |    1     |    1    
   1     |    1     |    2    
   1     |    2     |    1    
   1     |    2     |    2    
   2     |    1     |    1    
   2     |    1     |    2    
   2     |    2     |    1    
   2     |    2     |    2
```

So we have 8 rows (2 x 2 x 2). With more rows and more child tables the count can easily go into millions of rows.
But I want a result more like this:

```
child1ID | child2ID | child3ID
    1    |   NULL   |   NULL    
    2    |   NULL   |   NULL    
  NULL   |     1    |   NULL    
  NULL   |     2    |   NULL    
  NULL   |   NULL   |    1    
  NULL   |   NULL   |    2
```

Here we have only 6 rows (2 + 2 + 2) and even with more child tables the row count won't explode.

How can I achieve this?

By the way, I also looked at `UNION` and to use 3 selects, but that doesnt work as the table structure of the child tables is not identical (different column count and data types)
Also `GROUP BY` seems not to be a good way as the query would still fetch millions of rows before the grouping happens.

Comment: "but that resulted in a lot of unnecessary rows" In your question is missing the info on what you call "unnecessary rows"  Which data is in (i.e) child1, and which values do you want to show?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`. But there is not enough data available in the question to reproduce the output (read: [mre])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it!

Joining the rows not only by childN.foreignKey = parentTable.parentKey but also join them by row number does the trick:

```
SELECT
T1.child1ID,
T2.child2ID,
T3.child3ID
FROM parent
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rownum FROM child1) as T1 ON T1.parentID = parent.parentID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rownum FROM child2) as T2 ON T2.parentID = parent.parentID AND T2.rownum = T1.rownum
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rownum FROM child3) as T3 ON T3.parentID = parent.parentID AND T3.rownum = T1.rownum
WHERE parent.parentID = 1;
```

Important note: As MySQL does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN` the first joined table has to be the table with the most count of rows.

The result:

```
child1ID | child2ID | child3ID
   1     |    1     |    1    
   2     |    2     |    2
```

If we have multiple tables with different count of rows, but the table with most rows is the first joined table, then we have result something like this:

```
child1ID | child2ID | child3ID | child4ID | child5ID | child6ID
   1     |    1     |    1     |    1     |    1     |    1     |
   2     |    2     |    2     |   NULL   |    2     |    2     |
   3     |   NULL   |    3     |   NULL   |    3     |    3     |
   4     |   NULL   |   NULL   |   NULL   |    4     |   NULL   |
   5     |   NULL   |   NULL   |   NULL   |   NULL   |   NULL   |
```

I hope it helps others as well who try to join multiple tables to ONE parent table without getting all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot. You need two separate SQL statement. The reason being that you are dealing with cross product (join) and filter operations (where clause). You are already duplicating the parent as many times as there are childs. So, in fact, you could ask for a way to get the parent once along with the childs. That's not even possible with a single parent and child table. Why bother with more?

To get around the problem there are ORM libraries that kind of hide the problem without solving it. My personal feeling is that the cure is worse than the desease. The best framework I dealt with was ADO.Net which provide a good compromise with DataTables and the ability to traverse relations to access the child records.

Comment: I was expecting this somehow that the best approach would be to make separated select queries for that and combine data in PHP. But I hoped there would be a good way to do it with one SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You result is not reproduceable, see:

```
mysql> select * from child1;
+----------+----------+
| child1id | parentID |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |
|        1 |        2 |
+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from child2;
+----------+----------+
| child2id | parentID |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |
|        1 |        2 |
+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from child3;
+----------+----------+
| child3id | parentID |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |
|        1 |        2 |
+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    -> child1.child1ID,
    -> child2.child2ID,
    -> child3.child3ID
    -> FROM parent
    -> LEFT JOIN child1 ON child1.parentID = parent.parentID
    -> LEFT JOIN child2 ON child2.parentID = parent.parentID
    -> LEFT JOIN child3 ON child3.parentID = parent.parentID
    -> WHERE parent.parentID = 1;
+----------+----------+----------+
| child1ID | child2ID | child3ID |
+----------+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |        1 |
+----------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

see also, [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daff46/1)

edit: this produces desired results: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2d6e0/6)
The fiddle is adapted so "So childIDs are 1 and 2 with parentID 1"

Comment: as in my result table stated above parentID is '1' for all rows. So childIDs are 1 and 2 with parentID 1. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a3f18/1/0